# Use Differentiation to fine the absolute minimum and absolute maximums

Tags: derivatives

Find the absolut maximum and absolute minimum values of the function
f(x)= 4x/8x+4

On the interval 
[3,7]

I'm quite lost on this question, if someone can work through it completely so i have a worked example for further question sit would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the equality
$$\left(\frac fg\right)'=\frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}$$
we find that
$$f'(x)=\frac{4(8x+4)-8(4x)}{(8x+4)^2}=\frac{16}{(8x+4)^2}>0$$
hence $f$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[3,7]$ and then
$$\min f=f(3)=\frac{3}{7}\quad\text{and}\quad \max f=f(7)=\frac7{15}$$